# 2 Forms from seperate controller in 1 view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 controllers: `models_controller` and `portfolios_controller`

Rather than going to separate pages to fill in these forms, I'd like to display all of the forms in a single view and fill in all of the data at once.

Here's the **2 in 1 form** I'm trying to get to work: https://github.com/imjp/models/blob/master/app/views/models/_form.html.erb

What is the simplest way to achieve my goal according to current best practices?

**EDIT 1:** I've found a way to display the forms together in 1 view but there one problem, the submit button from the original form is throwing up errors if it needs to throw up validation errors:
`undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class`
Take a look at the link provided above.

Answer (score 1):

since **model :has_one portfolio**, the rails best practices is nested_attributes

```
#Model (https://github.com/imjp/models/blob/master/app/models/model.rb)
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :portfolio
...
end


#View (https://github.com/imjp/models/blob/master/app/views/models/_form.html.erb)
<% fields_for :portfolio |portfolio_form| %>
  ... 
  <div class="field">
    <%= portfolio_form.label :model_id %><br />
    <%= portfolio_form.number_field :model_id %>
  </div>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: no need to do any changes in the "models_controller.rb", because portfolio object will be saved when callback #save for model is triggered

Comment: Thanks for adding an answer mikhailov! 
However, the answer you've provided isn't working :( I get the following error: http://i.imgur.com/M2XR0.png

Comment: updated my answer - pass symbol instead of object. to see how it works in action, please take a look at the Railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: I went through the Railscasts episode but was unable to get his code to work in my app. Not sure if it has something to do with the fact that he's using like rails 2.3 or something.

`3.times { @model.portfolios.build }` does not work for me.. it says `undefined method for 'portfolios'`

Comment: you have "portfolio", not "portfolios" association. so use @model.build_portfolio instead

Comment: Thanks man! That almost fixes it as the only error I'm still getting is that the errors are not being displayed (validation errors):
<br>
`<% if @portfolio.errors.any? %>`<br>
   `<div id="error_explanation">`<br>
`    <h2><%= pluralize(@portfolio.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this portfolio from being saved:</h2>`<br>

`    <ul>`<br>
     `<% @portfolio.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>`<br>
`      <li><%= msg %></li>`<br>
`     <% end %>`<br>
`    </ul>`<br>
`   </div>`<br>
`  <% end %>`

Comment: @mikhailov let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1560/discussion-between-imjp-and-mikhailov)

Comment: you no need to get @portfolio.errors objects, because parent @model.errors object already includes all the errors together

Comment: I just realized this as well: there's only 1 submit button for the 2 forms.. my users will be filling in the forms seperately as I'm going to use different tabs to display the each form.

Is this still the best approach?

Comment: if you should be able to fill "portfolio" object independent, think about it as another one entity, not a child of "model". **accepts_nested_attributes_for** just creates methods with associations related attributes as own object's attribute

Comment: How would I display the form from portfolio as an independent object though? That was the original question >.>

Comment: use another partial with the form for independent object

Comment: I did. Do you have a minute to chat? This commenting system is pretty slow instead of real time chatting.